# GDI+ Bitmap Save problem

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi+

```
Bitmap bff(L"1.jpg");
bff.Save(L"2.jpg", &Gdiplus::ImageFormatJPEG, NULL);
```

This creates a new file 2.jpg with zero-bytes length. 
Isn't it supposed to write an image file that is identical to 1.jpg?

Why I'm having zero-bytes length files? 
I'm doing this test because writing other Bitmaps to files, result in the same output.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a fast way to save it, since [`GetEncoderClsid`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms533843(v=vs.85).aspx) is a custom function:

```
//Save to PNG
CLSID pngClsid;
CLSIDFromString(L"{557CF406-1A04-11D3-9A73-0000F81EF32E}", &pngClsid);
bmp.Save(L"file.png", &pngClsid, NULL);
```

and here's IDs for other formats:

```
bmp: {557cf400-1a04-11d3-9a73-0000f81ef32e}
jpg: {557cf401-1a04-11d3-9a73-0000f81ef32e}
gif: {557cf402-1a04-11d3-9a73-0000f81ef32e}
tif: {557cf405-1a04-11d3-9a73-0000f81ef32e}
png: {557cf406-1a04-11d3-9a73-0000f81ef32e}
```

Comment: @phimuemue: dude, it's been almost 2 yrs ago. I think I got them from reversing the GDI+ library itself.

Answer (score 1):

`&Gdiplus::ImageFormatJPEG` is the wrong value to send as the second parameter (thus why the new file is zero bytes large). Take a look at the code example at the bottom of the [`Image::Save()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535407(VS.85).aspx) reference page which demonstrates the proper usage of `Save()`.

Comment: When I'm using the code in the sample, the one with GetEncoderClsid, I'm getting an "Invalid Parameter" error. The return value of the method Save is 2. and nothing is written.

Comment: Looking back at your other question, you call `GetEncoderClsid()` yet you still end up passing `&Gdiplus::...` to `Save()`. You should instead be passing the CLSID that was given to you by `GetEncoderClsid()`

Comment: Also, could it be that JPEG encoder *requires* parameters? You are passing NULL as the third parameter, but could it be that for JPEG encoder the 'quality' setting is non-optional, as in this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533844(VS.85).aspx example?

Comment: AndreyT: For me, at least, `Save()` runs fine on JPEGs with a NULL third parameter

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, you can't just pass the image format GUID ('ImageFormatJPEG' in your case) to 'Image::Save' method. The second argument is supposed to hold the encoder GUID, not a format GUID. See an example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535407(VS.85).aspx)